# how to get loop's array values in every tr in ajax success

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

My Ajax code is below

```
var stack = new Array();
var item_ids_array = new Array();
var inc_i;
var f=0;

for(inc_i =0; inc_i <item_array_length; inc_i++)
{
    stack[f] = item_ids_array[inc_i];
    f=f+1;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/items/get_item_ids_info/"+item_ids_array[inc_i],
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
           $('<tr class="field" id="row'+item_ids_array[inc_i]+'">'+data+'</tr>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#sortable_table');
        }

    });
}
```

In Success, `item_ids_array[inc_i]` is doing display only last array value in every row(tr) ID if Row(tr) is append more than 1.

For Example if Row(tr) is three(3). then display only `item_ids_array[inc_i] = item_ids_array[2]`'s value in every tr ID.

Basically i need that `item_ids_array[inc_i]`'s value will display in every tr ID which will be different.

How to get different array value in tr in success.
Please help me.

Comment: Why not make one AJAX call to get all of the data, instead of separate ones?

Comment: Basically in tr, i am taking some table's td. But full row don't come in data. So i have taken only td. Please any help.

Comment: `item_array_length` is undefined here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your AJAX callbacks, they are all using the same `inc_i` variable.  Which, after the loop, will be the final value.

You need to add another closure to "capture" the `inc_i` value for each callback.

```
var stack = new Array();
var item_ids_array = new Array();
var inc_i;
var f=0;

function createCallback(i){
    return function(data){
        $('<tr class="field" id="row'+item_ids_array[i]+'">'+data+'</tr>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#sortable_table');
    };
}

for(inc_i =0; inc_i <item_array_length; inc_i++){

    stack[f] = item_ids_array[inc_i];
    f=f+1;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/items/get_item_ids_info/"+item_ids_array[inc_i],
        cache: false,
        success: createCallback(inc+i)    
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rocket Hazmat.May Allah Bless you.

Answer (score 1):

don't request ajax in loop that make more than one request are lost because of ajax time out .And may be you can solve this problem by using recursive function when the ajax request is success send another request .try this may be can help you

```
var f=0;
inc_i = 0;
var item_ids_array = new Array();
var stack = new Array();

function Y_fn(inc_i,f) {
        stack[f] = item_ids_array[inc_i];
        f=f+1;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/items/get_item_ids_info/"+item_ids_array[inc_i],
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
               $('<tr class="field" id="row'+item_ids_array[inc_i]+'">'+data+'</tr>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#sortable_table');
            inc_i +=1;
             Y_fn(inc_i,f);  // recursive function
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ahmed Atta. May Allah Bless you.